# Is it possible to bind '2M' to a single key in w3m?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, w3m

Pressing <kbd>M</kbd> in `w3m` launches the 1st external browser, <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> the second. While it is easy to bind the built-in command `EXTERN` to another key, is it possible to bind the second to another key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of using ***extbrowser*** (in ~/.w3m/configs).
which you have to use weird hotkeys thats hard to remember what each one does 2M, 3M, 4M ...etc or 2-Esc-Shift-M, 3-Esc-Shift-M, 4-Esc-Shift-M ...etc.
you are limited to 9 total also

you can bind hotkeys in your keymap file (**$EDITOR ~/.w3m/keymap**)

heres some examples:

```
# EXTERN_LINK = under cursor
# EXTERN      = current page

# yank url to clipboard
keymap  yy      EXTERN_LINK 'tmux set-buffer'
keymap  YY      EXTERN      'tmux set-buffer'
keymap  yx      EXTERN_LINK 'printf %s | xsel -b'
keymap  YX      EXTERN      'printf %s | xsel -b'

# open url in gui browser
keymap  xw      EXTERN_LINK '$BROWSER'
keymap  XW      EXTERN      '$BROWSER'
keymap  xn      EXTERN_LINK '$BROWSER_PRIVATE'
keymap  XN      EXTERN      '$BROWSER_PRIVATE'

# macros for smart search
keymap  sd      COMMAND "TAB_GOTO https://duckduckgo.com/lite/; NEXT_LINK; GOTO_LINK; SUBMIT"
keymap  sg      COMMAND "TAB_GOTO https://google.com; GOTO_LINE 6; NEXT_LINK; GOTO_LINK; SUBMIT"
keymap  sy      COMMAND "TAB_GOTO https://yewtu.be; NEXT_LINK; GOTO_LINK"
keymap  so      COMMAND "TAB_GOTO https://search.yahoo.com; GOTO_LINE 19; NEXT_LINK; GOTO_LINK"
```

toggle settings using macros: e.g hit **\n** will hide/show line numbers. more options **$ w3m -show-option**

```
keymap  \\\?    COMMAND "HELP; SEARCH ^User-Defined; CENTER_V"            # show user custom hotkeys binding
keymap  \\\f    COMMAND "HELP; SEARCH ^Input Line Editing Mode; CENTER_V" # show field hotkeys binding
keymap  \\\c    COMMAND "SET_OPTION color=toggle ; RESHAPE"
keymap  \\\u    COMMAND "SET_OPTION mark_all_pages=toggle ; RESHAPE" # Treat URL-like strings as links in all pages
keymap  \\\l    COMMAND "SET_OPTION display_link_number=toggle ; SET_OPTION show_lnum=toggle ; RESHAPE" # toggle hinting mode / line numbers
keymap  \\\h    COMMAND "SET_OPTION display_link_number=toggle ; RESHAPE" # toggle hinting mode
keymap  \\\n    COMMAND "SET_OPTION show_lnum=toggle ; RESHAPE"           # toggle line numbers
keymap  \\\b    COMMAND "SET_OPTION display_borders=toggle ; RESHAPE"     # toggle table borders
keymap  \\\i    COMMAND "SET_OPTION display_image=toggle ; RELOAD"        # toggle image display
keymap  \\\e    COMMAND "SET_OPTION user_agent='' ; RELOAD"               # empty user agent
keymap  \\\A    COMMAND "SET_OPTION user_agent='Opera/9.80 (S60; SymbOS; Opera Mobi/SYB-1107071606; U; en) Presto/2.8.149 Version/11.10' ; RELOAD"
```

you can even write scripts if is more complex then a simple one liner

```
# yank page title
keymap  \\\y    EXTERN_LINK ~/.w3m/cgi-bin/yanktitle_cursorurl.cgi  # yank title (cursor url)
```

e.g: **$EDITOR ~/.w3m/cgi-bin/yanktitle_cursorurl.cgi**

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
# DESC:   yank page title to X11 clipboard and tmux clipboard
# DEPEND: w3m wget gawk (xsel or tmux)

# get url from w3m envoriment variables (e.g !env | less)
# URL="$W3M_URL"            # current page url
URL="$W3M_CURRENT_LINK"   # current link on cursor

# yank page title
TITLE=$(wget -qO- "$URL" | gawk -v IGNORECASE=1 -v RS='</title' 'RT{gsub(/.*<title[^>]*>/,"");print;exit}')
printf "%s" "$TITLE" | xsel -b
printf "%s" "$TITLE" | tmux load-buffer -
```

Comment: I like that you think out of the box defined in my question.

Comment: just want to add that i had to restart `w3m` after saving `.w3m/keymap`, which seems normal to do but i saw my "user-defined key bindings", albeit after reloading the url, and they actually were not in effect, yet.

Comment: @nymo you can also bind a key to auto reload after saving `keymap ck COMMAND "LOAD ~/.w3m/keymap; EDIT; BACK; REINIT"`

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't possible. There is only a single EXTERN command, and it invokes the first, second or third browser depending on the preceding numeric argument. W3m doesn't have a macro facility: you can't bind a key to a sequence of commands.

You could use an external macro facility: have a key send `2M` when you're in w3m. That would require the macro facility to be aware of when you are in w3m. One way to do this is to always run w3m (and nothing else) in a dedicated screen or tmux configuration.

Comment: Thank you. Can the 'EXTERN' command take arguments? For example, 'EXTERN 2' or something similar?

Comment: @Jing Unfortunately, I don't think so.